# Как сделать с помощью flex-box меню где два блока с элементами будут располагаться по противоположным краям экрана

Tags: css, html5, flexbox, menu, site

Вот меню которое пытался повторить:
[image: Пример меню которое хотел повторить]

Надписи в навигации это 1 div, контент с правой стороны другой, можно ли с помощью flex поместить их по разным краям, или же на примере это реализовано иначе?

Я знаю как это осуществить через margin, но всё же хочу сделать по правильному если это возможно.

Прикреплю ссылку к примеру, сам из разметки сайта я ответ найти не смог:
https://www.riotgames.com/ru

Answer (score 0):

В примере по ссылке из вопроса центральному элементу задается свойство

```
flex: 1;
```

что соответствует [`flex-grow: 1`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) - растянуть этот элемент на все свободное пространство.

Comment: Какому центральному элементу?

Comment: там в менюшке с `display:flex` три элемента. тот который в центре - стоит `flex: 1;`

Answer (score -1):

```
.right-panel {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```